# Wordpress-Update Birth Date in Woocommerce Account

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, field

I tried to implement custom field into WooCommerce registration page on my site, and works great, but if want to Modify that date into [My Account page](http://www.ecosafai.com/my-account/), changes are not saved. Looks like i have missed something somewhere that don't proceed data to database. This is code for custom field:

```
<p class="form-row form-row-last">
<label for="reg_billing_birthdate"><?php _e( 'Date of Birth', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
<input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_birthdate" id="reg_billing_birthdate" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_birthdate'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_birthdate'] ); ?>" />
</p>
```

column billing_birthdate is created into wp_usermeta table, But i added this code also into functions.php into theme:

and this code to proceed data to database..

```
    /**
 * Below code save extra fields.
 */
   function wooc_save_extra_register_fields( $customer_id ) {
      if ( isset( $_POST['billing_birthdate'] ) ) {
         // Billing Address field which is by default
         update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'last_name', sanitize_text_field(     $_POST['billing_birthdate'] ) );
         // Last name field which is used in WooCommerce
         update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_birthdate',     sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_birthdate'] ) );
  }

}
```

I alse added this code to functions.php file, to be able to edit that field into edit-account page.

```
   /**
  * To display additional field at My Account page 
  * Once member login: edit account
  */
 add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form',    'my_woocommerce_edit_account_form' );

 function my_woocommerce_edit_account_form() {

$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$user = get_userdata( $user_id );

if ( !$user )
    return;

  $birthdate = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'birthdate', true );

 ?>
  <fieldset>

    <p class="form-row form-row-thirds">
        <label for="birthdate">Birth date:</label>
        <input type="text" name="birthdate" value="<?php echo esc_attr(    $birthdate ); ?>" class="input-text" />
        <br />
        <span style="font-size: 12px;">(Birth date format: DD-MM-YYYY. eg:     31-12-2005)</span>
    </p>
    </fieldset>

    <?php

   } // end func


   /**
   * This is to save user input into database
   * hook: woocommerce_save_account_details
   */
  add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details',     'my_woocommerce_save_account_details' );

  function my_woocommerce_save_account_details( $user_id ) {
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'birthdate', htmlentities( $_POST[   'birthdate' ] ) ); 
  } // end func
```

**So my question is where is my error my after editing that field into my-account page, changes are not reflected into account dashboard.**

Answer (score 2):

What I found that, you are updating the field called '**billing_birthdate**' at the time you are inserting the data. But when you are editing you are updating the field '**birthdate**'.
For update :

```
update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_birthdate',htmlentities( $_POST['birthdate'] ) );
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wanted to ask, where exactly to replace this row you suggested?

Comment: You need to replace update_user_meta( $user_id, 'birthdate', htmlentities( $_POST[   'birthdate' ] ) );  this line with the given line : update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_birthdate',htmlentities( $_POST['birthdate'] ) );

Comment: I tryed to replace your line with mine in this code:

`function my_woocommerce_save_account_details( $user_id ) {
 update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_birthdate',htmlentities( $_POST['birthdate'] ) ); 
} // end func`

but when try to modify birthdate, nothing is changed..

Comment: Please change the 'birthday' to 'billing_birthdate' where ever you have.... and please check database table wp_user_meta with 'billing_birthdate' for any user. If not found you need to go through your code again.

Comment: also please remove htmlentities and use sanitize_text_field

Comment: I changed "htmlentities" and use "sanitize_text_field" in row you suggested, but nothing changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135274/discussion-between-dora-and-tristup).